# Align a text and a image next to each other

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

How can I align a `div` which contains text and an image next to each other so that it remains fixed until the width is around 768px?

This is my code:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<div class="column_1">
   Contains bigger width
</div>
<div class="column_2">
<div class="imageSection">
<img src="http://www.smashbros.com/wii/en_uk/characters/images/link/link.jpg">
</div>
<div class="text">
<div class="text1">Data will be here</div>
<div class="text1">Data will be here</div>
<div class="text1">Data will be here</div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS styles

```
.column_1 {width:65%;}
.column_2 {width: 35%;}

.column_2 .imageSection {width:45%; display:block; float:left}
.column_2 text {width:45%}
```

Can anyone please let me know how to proceed. I am stuck at this point where I am unable to align it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check this, the `image` and the `content` are placed next to each other until `768px` and for screens smaller than `768px`, the image is stacked above the `content`.

```css
 .column_1 {
     width:65%;
 }
 .column_2 {
     width: 35%;
 }
 .column_2 .imageSection {
     width:45%;
     display:block;
     float: left;
 }
 .column_2 text {
     width:45%
 }
 @media (max-width: 768px) {
     .column_2 .imageSection {
         float: none;
     }
 }
```

```html
<div class="column_1">Contains bigger width</div>
<div class="column_2">
    <div class="imageSection">
        <img src="http://www.smashbros.com/wii/en_uk/characters/images/link/link.jpg" width="100%">
    </div>
    <div class="text">
        <div class="text1">Data will be here</div>
        <div class="text1">Data will be here</div>
        <div class="text1">Data will be here</div>
    </div>
</div>
```